# "Shared" and "__gshared" Keywords in D

Tags: shared, d

When **not** used inside a `static` context (that is, when the `static` keyword isn't present, and you're not in global scope), what do the `shared` and `__gshared` keywords do?

Examples:

```
struct Temp
{
       shared int i;
    __gshared int j;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shared int is typed `shared(int)`, which doesn't *do* anything but give it that type. The `__gshared int` is a no-op -- DMD is fond of ignoring no-op attributes.

Comment: __gshared is not a no-op.  It implies static.

Comment: Also: while `shared int` only behaves like a type qualifier (e.g. like `const`) in the current implementation of dmd for local variables, a properly implemented `shared` - the way I understand it - should have read-acquire and write-release-semantics (i.e. use memory fences on many architectures and avoid certain compiler optimizations, see also http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/faq.html#shared_memory_barriers). This would occasionally be relevant even for local variables, e.g., in the case of a closure executed within other threads (or in the rare case of cross-thread stack access).

Answer (score 3):

D2 defaults to Thread Local Storage, while C, C++ and D1 default to global storage.

One of the differences is that a global variable in D is visible to other threads, while TLS is not.

This may not sound like much, but try interfacing to a C library without realizing this.  (immutable is. global as well)

IME __gshared pretty much only exists to force something into global when normally it would not.

there may be other uses for it, but I haven't seen any.

An example would be a global variable in a C header.  If you try to interface with it, you'll need immutable or __gshared.  There are other ways of course, but this is probably easiest.